# Chandelier with 6 bulbs does not work on dimmer switch after bulb has been replaced

Tags: electrical, dimmer-switch, bulb, halogen

A halogen bulb blew and I replaced it with the dimmer switch on and all 6 bulbs work and can be dimmed.When I switch it off and then back on none of the bulbs light.If I take out the bulb I replaced  the 5 other bulbs work and dim.The bulb is a dimmable halogen bulb.
The others are halogen bulbs but are older and may be a different make.

Comment: "I replaced it with the dimmer switch on" can you expand on that? Does that mean that you pulled the dead bulb out and put the replacement in while the other lights were on?

Comment: Can we assume you've tried it with the dimmer at it's maximum setting?

Comment: Also, I'm a little suspicious about the 'dimmable halogen bulb'.  AFAIK, all halogen bulbs are dimmable.  It's LED and CFL bulbs that may or may not be compatible with dimmer switches.  Are you sure it's halogen?

Comment: This sounds like the basis of a great magic act. Boom! On! ...  Bazoom! Off!

Comment: Is the new lamp the same wattage as the originals? When they do light are all the lamps aprox the same brightness?